# Implementing EPiServer in a Windows Service

Tags: episerver

So my problem is that I have a simple windows service that looks at some incoming files and then create some epi-data using the IContentRepository.

I am running the latest version of epi 9.7.2

I have downloaded the needed nuget packages.

When i try with simplest possible:

```cs
var repo = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
```

I get an expected error since EPi has not been initialized properly.

So my question is: How do I initialize EPiServer in a windows service (or console app, which I guess would be the same problem)

Comment: Even though Episerver _can_ be bootstrapped outside of a web app (for integration tests etc), it might be worth considering implementing that logic as part of your website instead, and have the service invoke an API exposed by the web app?

Comment: I agree, and I would probable do some kind of scheduled job if I were to start from scratch. In this case though the real service already exist and my job is only to make it work in EPi 9.

Comment: Wrong approach, build a webservice in EPiServer and integrate with the api from your windows service